# Can't uninstall NetSuite SuiteCommerce Base Theme

Tags: themes, netsuite, suitecommerce

I tried to install this "SuiteCommerce Base Theme" theme bundle in NetSuite. But the bundle remained in 'failure' status. Now i want to uninstall this bundle, however it doesn't allow mw to uninstall this bundle form NetSuite. Have anyone faced this issue before? or any one has anyone any idea on how to fix this issue?.

The error says:

```
Unexpected Error

Your uninstall of bundle 245,062 failed: 
Ticket: joo6zrga174q66lgr8f1e.
```

For reference:

[image: See the bundle(theme) is in failed status]

Answer (score 0):

I would just submit a ticket to NetSuite support. Something isn't working right.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know I am years late. However I just had this issue. I solved my issue with the following, there are script deployment records tied to these bundles, go under script deployments and undeploy the scripts associated with the bundle. Maybe this will help.